# How to emulate mouse clicking/mouse moving/key typing in the global context?

Tags: input, keyboard, mouse, global, emulation

**Emulate** means to invoke these events programatically.

**Global context** means that these event invocations should affect the whole desktop (sort of global environment) rather than the application which produces them. Moreover, the application itself should have no windows - it has to simply execute in background and produce these events due to some logic. In other words, if, for example, this application puts mouse in "global" arbitrary position and invokes a double click event and there is an icon of some other application under the cursor then this "other" application should start.

Which library can I use to achieve it?

Note: I don't specify OS since I hope that the library is supposed to do it in a cross-platform way. If that's not possible then I will be fine with the Windows only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Java's `java.awt.Robot` has all requested features.